# How to get server datetime without postback using JSOM or services

Tags: javascript, web-services, client-object-model

My application page may be long time without reloading, and user changed system date and time. And I need to know datetime from server, **not from client**.

Comment: I can insert new item to the event list, and take its Created value. But may be there clear solution?

Comment: That would work, created by is generated by SharePoint and won't change. I guess it depends on how you need to use it. Developing a web service to do tht might be unnedded overhead/extra managed code to maintain.

Comment: Maybe you could use the JS variable _spPageContextInfo.clientServerTimeDelta but I am not sure, haven't used that before.

Comment: Have you seen http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/130179/627 ?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint? Different versions have different context information injected into each page. For example, in SharePoint Online Classic pages you can use _spPageContextIno.serverTime.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a custom webservice that returns the server time and call this through JS.

Comment: Thank you, Steve! This is unexpected and original for me. I'll do it.

Comment: Best thing is that it is universal way for all complex tasks.

Comment: ashx is simpler!

Comment: There's a [Stack Exchange](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269657/right-way-to-get-web-server-time-and-display-it-on-web-pages) question about it w/ JS/PHP and JS/HTML solutions for it.

Comment: I'm not sure the Stack Exchange question is related since it's PHP and SharePoint is ASP.NET